# Attributed text UILabel cut off in UICollectionViewCell but not in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uicollectionview, uilabel

Attributed text UILabel inside a UICollectionViewCell is cut off after scrolling (autolayout turned on).

Why does the same setup in a UITableViewCell is working fine. (the constraints / priority levels are identical as well)

Using a custom font & word wrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved it by providing the cell width for the UILabel property preferredMaxLayoutWidth minus possible offsets you are using in your layout.

```
self.yourUIlabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - yourOffsets;
```

Found the answer here: http://johnszumski.com/blog/auto-layout-for-table-view-cells-with-dynamic-heights

Similar questions: [Word Wrap not working for UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142777/word-wrap-not-working-for-uilabel) & [UILabel not wrapping text correctly sometimes (auto layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513794/uilabel-not-wrapping-text-correctly-sometimes-auto-layout)

But some question remains why I didn't need this property inside the UITableViewCell